# MongoDB aggregation $out step: store data in another database

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, pentaho, bigdata

I'm building a new big data project and we are using MongoDB as operational database. We use Pentaho Kettle to run the ETL that processes and cleans de data.

In a step of this ETL we make a MongoDB aggregation pipeline with the next operators in this order:

```
{$unwind: '$metrics'},
{$match:{'metrics.event.name': 'Hover',
          'observationTime':{
            $gte:{
                 $date:"${DATA}"
            }
          }
       }
     },
{ $project : { '_id': 0,
                'remoteLocation':1,
                 "remoteIP":1,
                 "language" : 1,
                 "observationTime" : 1,
                 "device" : 1,
                 "session_ID" : 1,
                 "user_ID" : 1,
                 "metrics" : 1,
              }
},
{ $out: "Hover_tmp"}
```

My problem is that this query is executed over a replica database, so I cannot write there and that's what `$out` does in the final step.

A posible solution would be specify a collection of another non-replica MongoDB database.

Is that posible ?
Do you find any other solution?

Comment: From the [documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/#create-new-collection) *"The $out operation creates a new collection in the current database"*. Moreover, you seem to be talking about another "instance". So rather you iterate the cursor and write to the other instance.

Comment: Yes, I'm talking about inserting in another instance.

Currently, I'm using a MongoDB Input component to retrive the data of the replica database using a aggregation pipeline. 

Do you know any solution (or component) to "iterate the cursor" as you sayed and solve the problem?

We decided to use $out because sometimes we reach de 16 mb MongoDB document limit. Have you ever have this problem? Did you find any solution?

As you can see, it's my first big data project using MongoDB and Pentaho Data Integration.

Thank you very much for your help.